# SQL Server - Procedure to return results of dynamic Query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have a rather simple stored procedure that needs to return a results set, something like (the code is a highly simplified version of the real one, but is enough to describe my problem):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc(@Par1 VARCHAR(100)) 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT A,B,C FROM MyTable ;
END ;
```

This, so far, works perfectly as the invoking procedure does get the values A,B and C of all the records in that table.

Now, I need to allow the addition of "conditions" (i.e. WHERE clause) as provided through the received parameter `Par1`. To do that, I declare a new local variable aimed to hold a full SQL select statement that would include the conditions, so the same procedure would now look like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc(@Par1 VARCHAR(100)) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQLSTT VARCHAR(1000) ;
    SET @SQLSTT = 'SELECT A,B,C FROM MyTable WHERE ' + @Par1 ;

    EXECUTE ( @SQLSTT );
END ;
```

This **ALMOST** work: The correct number of records are affected, but they are not passed to the invoking procedure.

I thought of using a temporary table (or table variable), but it would be an unneeded overhead since, once the records are selected, there is no further manipulation to take place within this procedure and only need to be passed on to the invoking SP.

So, my question is: What should be the correct syntax to achieve what I want?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I found the issue. It had nothing to do with the procedure (i.e. `MyProc`) but rather with the way I was attempting to see the returned results. Quick fix and it all works are needed.

Thanks for all that took the time to walk though my question and send comments/suggestions/answers.

Comment: Which procedure do you mean "they are not passed to the invoking procedure" ?

Comment: OK I think I get it, and edited my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a table to hold the return.

```
 declare @ret table (a int, b int, c int)
 insert into @ret
 EXECUTE ( @SQLSTT );
```

Comment: Thank you for your remark, though it had nothing to do with my problem (which I solved). My problem had to do with the way I was attempting to "watch" at the results, and not their generation. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You don't really need a table variable. Since the executed string is a select in itself, the results are sent to the parent SP as if there was a static select.

Answer (score 0):

You must use @ in front of your parameter

The updated procedure is as follows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc(@Par1 VARCHAR(100)) 
AS
  BEGIN
     DECLARE @SQLSTT VARCHAR(1000) ;
     SET @SQLSTT = 'SELECT A,B,C FROM MyTable WHERE ' + @Par1 ;

     EXECUTE ( @SQLSTT );
  END ;
```

Comment: Of course. The example I presented is not a copy of my code. Edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your remark, though it had nothing to do with my problem (which I solved). My problem had to do with the way I was attempting to "watch" at the results, and not their generation. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine. I changed it to use NVARCHAR. Please check how you are calling the procedure with appropriate single quotations:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc(@Par1 NVARCHAR(100)) 
AS

    DECLARE @SQLSTT NVARCHAR(1000) ;
    SET @SQLSTT = N'SELECT A,B,C FROM MyTable WHERE ' + @Par1 ;
    EXEC( @SQLSTT )
```

Example call:

```
exec MyProc 'A <>''myvalue'''
```